How to "reflect and combine" (mirror?) a function about an arbitrary plane?
I am looking for a general method to "reflect and combine" a function about an arbitrary plane defined by a normal vector through the origin, in both 2D and 3D. Ideally, the method should be able to be computed efficiently on a GPU.
I'm probably not naming this "reflect and combine" operation correctly, which may be why I cannot find much info on it, so I will attempt to describe what I mean. Please let me know if there is a more standard or common name for this operation. Maybe to "mirror" a function, but that did not come up with any helpful answers. "Reflect and clip"?
As a simple 2D example function, consider the straight line y = x + 1 (red line).
To reflect this (or any) function about the y axis, we simply need to flip the sign of x, i.e. y = (-x) + 1 (blue line), which reflects the function about the normal vector [1, 0].

To "reflect and combine" a function about the y axis, we instead take the absolute value of x, which clips the function at the y axis and mirrors the positive x values, similar to a ray of light bouncing off of a mirror: y = abs(x) + 1 (green line).

The method to reflect a function about an arbitrary plane is known, for example see here  and here. I.e. r=d−2(d⋅n)n where d⋅n is the dot product, and n must be normalized (from the first link).
Is there a similar method for "reflecting and combining" a function about an arbitrary plane?

I'm not sure this is well-defined as there may not be a point of intersection. For example $f(x)=\frac1x$ and its mirror across the $x$-axis has no point of intersection.

Intersection at the plane of reflection is not required. If the function does not intersect the plane, it should just be duplicated on the opposite side. For example, abs(1/x) correctly combines the positive x portion of the function with its reflection about the y axis. Even though it doesn't intersect its reflection, it is still a single function with mirror symmetry.
